# GetObject() on bitmap handle from LoadImage() sometimes returns incorrect bitmap size

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

We are seeing an intermittent problem in which owner drawn buttons under Windows XP that are using a bitmap as a backdrop are displaying the bitmap incorrectly.  The window containing multiple buttons that are using the same bitmap file for the bitmap image used for the button backdrop will display and most of the buttons will be correct though in some cases there may be one or two buttons which are displaying the bitmap backdrop reduced to a smaller size.

If you exit the application and then restart it you may see the same behavior of the incorrect display of the icon on the buttons however it may or may not be the same buttons as previously.  Nor is this behavior of incorrect display of icons on the buttons always seen.  Sometimes it shows and sometimes it does not.  Since once we load an icon for a button we just keep it, once the button is displayed incorrectly it will always be displayed incorrectly.

Using the debugger we have finally found that what appears to be happening is that when the `GetObject()` function is called, the data returned for the bitmap size is sometimes incorrect.  For instance in one case the bitmap was 75x75 pixels and the size returned by `GetObject()` was 13x13 instead.  Since this size is used as part of the drawing of the bitmap, the displayed backdrop becomes a small decoration on the button window.

The actual source area is as follows.

```
if (!hBitmapFocus) {
    CString iconPath;
    iconPath.Format(ICON_FILES_DIR_FORMAT, m_Icon);
    hBitmapFocus = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, iconPath, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
}
if (hBitmapFocus) {
    BITMAP   bitmap;
    int iNoBytes = GetObject(hBitmapFocus, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
    if (iNoBytes < 1) {
        char xBuff[128];
        sprintf (xBuff, "GetObject() failed. GetLastError = %d", GetLastError ());
        NHPOS_ASSERT_TEXT((iNoBytes > 0), xBuff);
    }
    cxSource = bitmap.bmWidth;
    cySource = bitmap.bmHeight;
    //Bitmaps cannot be drawn directly to the screen so a 
    //compatible memory DC is created to draw to, then the image is 
    //transfered to the screen
    CDC hdcMem;
    hdcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

    HGDIOBJ  hpOldObject = hdcMem.SelectObject(hBitmapFocus);

    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    //The Horizontal and Vertical Alignment
    //For Images
    //Are set in the Layout Manager
    //the proper attribute will have to be checked against
    //for now the Image is centered on the button

    //Horizontal Alignment
    if(btnAttributes.horIconAlignment == IconAlignmentHLeft){//Image to left
        xPos = 2;
    }else if(btnAttributes.horIconAlignment == IconAlignmentHRight){//Image to right
       xPos = myRect.right - cxSource - 5;
    }else {//Horizontal center
       xPos = ((myRect.right - cxSource) / 2) - 1;
    }

    //Vertical Alignment
    if(btnAttributes.vertIconAlignment == IconAlignmentVTop){//Image to top
        yPos = 2;
    }else if(btnAttributes.vertIconAlignment == IconAlignmentVBottom){//Image to bottom
        yPos = myRect.bottom - cySource - 5;
    }else{//Vertical Center
        yPos = ((myRect.bottom - cySource) / 2) - 1;
    }

    pDC->BitBlt(xPos, yPos, cxSource, cySource, &hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    hdcMem.SelectObject(hpOldObject);
}
```

Using the debugger we can see that the `iconPath` string is correct and the bitmap is loaded as `hBitmapFocus` is not NULL.  Next we can see that the call to `GetObject()` is made and the value returned for `iNoBytes` equals 24.  For those buttons that display correctly the values in `bitmap.bmWidth` and `bitmap.bmHeight` are correct however for those that do not the values are much too small leading to an incorrect sizing when drawing the bitmap.

The variable is defined in the class header as

```
HBITMAP hBitmapFocus;
```

As part of doing the research for this I found this [stack overflow question, GetObject returns strange size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315227/getobject-returns-strange-size) and I am wondering if there is some kind of an alignment issue here.

Does the `bitmap` variable used in the call to `GetObject()` need to be on some kind of an alignment boundary?  While we are using packed for some of our data we are using `pragma` directives to only specify specific portions of code containing specific structs in include files that need to be packed on one byte boundaries.

Comment: You say "there may be one or two buttons which are displaying the bitmap backdrop reduced to a smaller size". `BitBlt` does not scale the image when it draws - passing a smaller size would clip the image rather than scale it. Did you actually mean the image is clipped or are you indeed seeing the full image shrunk to a smaller size? If the latter then the problem is in the image that is actually being loaded rather than in the rendering of it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter the bitmaps used are typically colors of some kind or another so it is hard to tell.  However the problem appears to be with GetObject() returning the wrong data rather than a BitBlt () problem.  What I expect is that the image is getting clipped because when passing the size to BitBlt() the size calculation is incorrect because the size reported by GetObject() is incorrect.  I doubt this is an alignment problem based on the memory addresses for the bitmap variable that I am seeing.  The same address is often used for the next button and the data will be correct for it.

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, I realize that there may be a problem with the bitmap handle for some reason.  So tomorrow I am going to make a modification to the code to do a GetObject() immediately after doing the LoadImage() to perform a check on the bitmap size at the time the bitmap is loaded.  I will perform an edit on the question with the result of that change.

Comment: I made a change to capture additional information and am no longer seeing the problem.  <sigh>

Comment: Always great when that happens :)

Comment: I have modified the source so that at the time the bitmap is first loaded, we go ahead and get the dimensions of the bitmap and keep them rather than using the values returned by a call to GetObject() each time.  I have kept the original GetObject() call and am doing a comparison of the two dimensions (one obtained at the time the bitmap is loaded and one at the point it is used) with a log if they differ.  The goal is to see if the problem resurfaces and if the new procedure eliminates the problem.

Comment: The problem has resurfaced despite the new procedure.  There appears to be a problem with the Windows API such that the GetObject() function is returning the wrong bitmap dimensions.  <sigh> <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158898) how to load a bitmap with palette information. It has a great example as well.

On the side note: I do not see anywhere in your code where you call ::DeleteObject(hBitmapFocus). It is very important to call this, as you can run out of GDI objects very quickly.

It is always a good idea to use Windows Task manager to see that your program does not exhaust the GDI resources. Just add "GDI Objects" column to the Task Manager and see that the number of objects is not constantly increasing in your app, but stays within an expected range, similar to other programs

Comment: Thanks for the link and I will take a look.  However I am still curious why the bitmap data is usually right but sometimes wrong.  The code provided is actually just a part of the code where the bitmap is displayed and as part of being displayed, a check to see if there is an icon to be put onto the button is checked.  Once created the bitmap is kept until such time as the button is destroyed.  The destructor for the button object does a DeleteObject if there is a bitmap associated with the button.  Not all buttons will have a bitmap.

Comment: I took a look at the link provided and am not sure that it actually provides any information about the problem that I am seeing.  The example appears to be doing something that I am not.  My problem is that the bitmap size information I am retrieving using GetObject() is incorrect.  However thinking about this further, I am going to make a change to use GetObject() immediately after the LoadImage() to check the size immediately after doing the LoadImage().

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int saved_dc = hdcMem.SaveDC();
HGDIOBJ  hpOldObject = hdcMem.SelectObject(hBitmapFocus);
hdcMem.RestoreDC(saved_dc);
```

It might work, don't ask me why though. I had similar problems in loading a series of bitmaps from disk and randomly it would scrw the colour map somehow (intermittently) showing only 5 colours instead of full 32bit colour depth.

The DC was getting corrupt for some unexplainable reason by the SelectObject() despite the fact of the actual bitmap images being produced uniformly and with the same attributes etc.

Comment: *"It might work, don't ask me why though."* - If you don't know why your code works, it doesn't. Quote me on that.

Comment: Perhaps poor wording on my part but I think I am giving my explanation later on on why this would work, if the person with the problem is actually experiencing the same unexplained behaviour with GDI then I can't see why this would not be a valuable answer from his perspective. You've been quite rash in penalising my answer. The 'I don't know why' part is mostly due to how Microsoft's GDI library is purported to work one way but actually works differently in practice (and this will not be their first library to do that). If you are an xp programmer you know what I mean.

Comment: [Device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) work as advertised. If *your* DC turns *"corrupt for some unexplainable reason,"* your code is incorrect. *"You've been quite rash in penalising my answer."* - This isn't a social network. I cast a vote on the value of a contribution. That is not to be mistaken for judging the contribution's author. I could well have a fun evening with you in a bar and still call this contribution *"not useful"*. I'm not grading personalities. I'm voting on the value of contributions.

Comment: "Device contexts work as advertised" - I doubt that is the case across versions. My code worked for GDI for years flawlessly but not for GDI+, so clearly there is some issue with backwards compatibility here.

Comment: I never asked to be liked as a person, or be liked at all but I do think you are jumping into conclusions and passing judgement on things you have not full picture on too easily. This is not the right way of thinking and acting let alone judging.

Btw, in spite of what you think, the proposal I made actually resolved my issue. Hopefully it might do so for our friend.

Comment: *"My code worked for GDI for years flawlessly but not for GDI+, so clearly there is some issue with backwards compatibility here."* - I have code that worked flawlessly **for decades** with any combination of USER, GDI, and GDI+. Whatever issue you make out is not someone else's fault. It is yours. Your code has bugs that just happened to surface when moving platforms. If you feel this analysis is inaccurate, ask a specific question, and we'll see how to address your bugs.

Comment: Are you Microsoft? Because you say "we". I don't want any further resolution of my issues. I came here only to propose a resolution of a potential problem that the originator of this question might be facing.

If you are Microsoft why don't you start backwards, the above code resolved my problem, what does it do and at what level to cause that? The answer from a user standpoint is obvious, but you as an MS engineer might know more. What would jumble up a DC after a call to SelectObject(). Investigating from all angles both the argument to this function and the returned objects are valid.

Comment: But in any case I don't want to waste any more of your time. I know my code is kosher (in terms of mem management and validity of objects) and I am happy with the above resolution I have found because this might actually be a genuine MS issue as many people as myself have found with other libraries as well when MS 'improves' core libraries from version to version of their O/S'.